# How to perform a JQuery script when the user click on a link and retrieve the link content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am pretty new in jQuery and I have the following problem.

In my HTML I have a link like this:

```
<a>SAIC831003</a>
```

When the link is clicked I need to perform a jQuery script when this link is clicked and into this script retrieve the content of the `<a>` tag.

I think that I can use an `onClick()` on the `<a>` tag (but I don't know if it is the best solution) and I don't know how retrieve the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the job :

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        alert($(this).text()); // Will alert the content of the a tag
    });
});
```

Comment: ad if I also need to specify a specific class for the a tag clicked?

Comment: Just change the css selector `'a'` by `a.my-class`.